# I want to remove void from volume of cube script

Tags: scripting, add-on

I have two problems

1. Getting Volume its return volume before object Edit and didn't change with editing object
2. I want here to remove Void From Cube what ever is it  (x,y,z)

   **For each cube selected Remove volume of Void inside selected Cube from its volume**
   `Print ( "Void.name.0000" ,Dim x , Dim y , Dim z,"Volume=" ,result )`

For Explain  Want to remove B Volume From A Volume
With Printing Name of void
lets Say B is another Cube

```
+----+----+----+----+
|   A               |
|                   |
+    +----+         +
|    |    |         |
|    | B  |         |
+    +----+         +
|                   |
|                   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

```
#*********************Getting Volume  *******************************
import bpy, bmesh
 
result =0 
 
for sel in bpy.context.selected_objects:
   
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( sel.data )

    vol       = float( bm.calc_volume() )
    vol_scale = ( '%.0E' % vol )[-3:]
    result+=bm.calc_volume()
    
    # I want here to remove Void From Cube what ever DIM is it (x,y,z)
    Print ( "Void.name.0000" ,Dim_x , Dim_y , Dim_z, "Volume=",result ) 
    print( "Volume=" , Dim_x , Dim_y , Dim_z, result  )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. What you want to do is a bit unclear. Are A and B two separated meshes?

Comment: Is the word "void" equal to "hollow volume"? You want to carve out a hollow cave from A cube using B cube?